# How to find unnamed component in jsf/primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In a primefaces/jsf webpage, I am unable to locate which of my components does not have an id, since the generated client side id is `j_idt42:police-table-id:policeler`. Can anyone help me to find which component is it?

Shortly, I have a full page layout. In the center of this layout, I define the content with one of my composite components. And lastly, inside this composite implementation, there is a datatable located inside a form. Form's id is `police-table-id`, dataTable's id is `policeler`.

layout.xhtml

```
<p:layoutUnit id="center-id" position="center" resizable="true">
    <ui:insert name="content">Put default content here, if any.</ui:insert>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

mycomposite.xhtml

```
<composite:implementation>
    <h:form id="police-table-id">
        <p:growl id="police-table-messages" />

        <p:dataTable id="policeler" var="pol"
            value="#{cc.attrs.policeBeanName.objectList}"...
```

actualPage.xhtml

```
<ui:define name="content">

        <denovo:poli... />
</ui:define>
```

generated html is as follows:
[image]

I suppose, I need to be able to give an id to the div in red rectangle whose classes are `ui-layout-unit-content` and `ui-widget-content`. However, i cannot give id to `ui:define` component, can I?

Also, any help about how to express my problem in a more coherent way is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composite component is a [naming container](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/cc/interface.html), which (among other things) means they add a "level" to the clientId generated by JSF.

Just name your *invocation* of the component:

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <denovo:poli id="mycomponent" ... />
</ui:define>
```